# Function for getting headers, body and http code for given url?

Tags: php

PHP Function for getting headers, body and http code for given url ?
Curl library don't have best mechanism for parsing and manipulation http headers so this function would be very handy. It is tiresome use some big and robust libraries for small script that need this kind of function.

Comment: omg, you can use $http_response_header  with curl.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function for doing this with curl:

```
<?php
function get_url_data($url, $timeout = 5){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,  $timeout );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);
    $headers  = explode( "\n", $header );

    $code = 0;
    if(isset($headers[0])){
        if(preg_match('/[0-9]{3}/', $headers[0], $matches)){
            $code = $matches[0];
        }
    }

    return ['code' => $code, 'headers' => $headers, 'body' => $body];
}

echo '<pre>';
$timeout = 5;
$url = "http://www.ebay.com";
$results = get_url_data($url, $timeout);
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
```

Example is tested and work fine, enjoy.